# Get ssid of WiFi depending on the state of WiFi

Tags: shell-script, shell, wifi

I'm writing a bar script and I don't want to check WiFi's ssid and it's state every 20/30 seconds when I know that it won't change for a while. I would like to use something like bspc's command `subscribe report` which updates only if there is a change.

Here is what I have for context:

```
while :
do
    case "con=$(cat /sys/class/net/w*/operstate 2>/dev/null)" in
        [Dd]*) ssid='No Connection' ;;
        [Uu]*) ssid=$(iwgetid -r) ;;
    esac

    echo "$ssid"
    sleep 30
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I probably did a terrible job at explaining what I want the script to actually do, so here is a better version:

I don't want to refresh the bar every 20/30 seconds just to display the same ssid every time, I only want to refresh it if there is a different output from the script.

I did find a solution by total accident:

```
# This function checks if the line is actually different or not,
# it's stolen from herbstluftwm example script
uniq_linebuffered() {
  awk -W interactive '$0 != l { print ; l=$0 ; fflush(); }' "$@"
}

while :
do
    case "con=$(cat /sys/class/net/w*/operstate 2>/dev/null)" in
        [Dd]*) ssid='No Connection' ;;
        [Uu]*) ssid=$(iwgetid -r) ;;
    esac

    echo "$ssid"
    sleep 10 || break
done > >(uniq_linebuffered) &
```